# @RequestBody not working- Returned Http Status 415 unsupported media type in Jquery

Tags: ajax, json, spring-mvc

I am using Spring 3.1 to develop my project. During the work I stuck at a point and really need your help.

My requirement is from client I will receive JSON object and will return JSON object too. I am successful to implement the same when I am using get post and delete request send from Server. But when I am using `PUT` method to send my data facing some problem. Because `PUT` cant receive data in `@ModelAttribute` I am using `@RequestBody` annotation to receive my data send from client.

When I use `@RequestBody MultiValueMap<String, String>` body get a error

> Http Status 415 unsupported media type.

When I try to receive data with `@RequestBody DemandBean` (my project Bean) I receive the following error.

> org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('o' (code 111)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
>   at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@19 d688; line: 1, column: 2]

But I am quite sure that I have mapped my jackson library properly because with `@RequestBody` I can receive the json back to client and also can send Json and spring can parse with `@ModelAttribute` in case of method is `GET`,`POST`,`DELETE`.

Below I am giving the code :

**Html FIle to send data:**

```
 var jsonStr = $("#searchDemand_frm").serializeArray();

 $("#searchResultTable td").remove();

 alert(JSON.stringify(jsonStr)); // Return proper form data in json format

 $.ajax({
    contentType : "application/json",
    dataType : 'json',
    type : "PUT",
    url : targetUrl,
    data : jsonStr,
    async : false,
    success : function(data) {
       alert("In Success");
    },
    error : function(request, status, error) {
       showPermissionDenied(request);
    }
});
```

**Json format send to server:**

```
[{"name":"opportunityId","value":"ad"},{"name":"dem andId","value":"hgh"},{"name":"demandCreator","val ue":"hghhgh"},{"name":"demandOwner","value":"hg"}, {"name":"status","value":"IP"},{"name":"region","v alue":"hgh"}]
```

**-Servlet.xml:**

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<context:component-scan base-package="com.ericsson.rms.controller.*" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.ericsson.rms.application.authorizatio n" />
<context:annotation-config/>

<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true" />

<bean id="jacksonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
   <property name="messageConverters">
      <list>
         <ref bean="jacksonMessageConverter" />
      </list>
   </property>
</bean>
```

**Controller Class:**

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public @ResponseBody
   List<DemandBean> searchDemandDetailsWithPut(@RequestBody DemandBean demand, 
                                               HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the json you are submitting from an array of objects to an object containing other objects, ie:

```
{{"name":"opportunityId","value":"ad"},{"name":"dem andId","value":"hgh"},{"name":"demandCreator","val ue":"hghhgh"},{"name":"demandOwner","value":"hg"}}
```

Instead of

```
[{"name":"opportunityId","value":"ad"},{"name":"dem andId","value":"hgh"},{"name":"demandCreator","val ue":"hghhgh"},{"name":"demandOwner","value":"hg"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and in my case the problem was not the ajax post: since I had associated the ajax call to the click of a form button, after making the ajax request the form was submitted and that was causing the error. Preventing the form to be submitted resolved the issue:

```
$('#btn_confirm').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();     // do not submit the form
    // your ajax call here
}
```